# How to open two notepad files together from a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

This is a Batch file.

```
java -jar "C:\Users\Clustering.jar" > E:\distMatrix.txt
notepad E:\distMatrix.txt
notepad E:\dendrogram_output.txt

pause
```

I want to open both the notepad files together ....
'cause when distMatrix opens, dendrogram_output does not open until the previous one is closed!
What should I do?

Answer (score 11):

Use `start`:

```
start notepad E:\distMatrix.txt
start notepad E:\dendrogram_output.txt
```

Note that once you have an argument with spaces in it, you need to use

```
start "" notepad "E:\some file with spaces.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case that answer works, But sometimes you will need to use the "/B" parameter with "start" command to run a program in the "background" without wait to close the first.

```
Start /B program1.exe
Start /B program2.exe
```

Bye.